# if isset not working with auto image upload

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

I have a form that uses `JQuery` to auto submit the form immediately after the file has been selected.

The image is uploaded and displays correctly but no data is inserted into the table.

I have tried removing the 'if isset' to test the `SQL` inserts data correctly and it does but obviously the if statement is needed so it doesn't insert data to the table every time the page is loaded.

I assume the problem is because I have removed the forms submit button however if I add it back in the form no longer auto submits after image has been selected.

```
$('#file').change(function() {
  $('#target').submit();
});
```

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
  DB::query('INSERT INTO images VALUES(\'\', :image, :img_id)',array(':image'=>$image, ':img_id'=>$userid));
}
<form id="target" action="upload.php" name="target" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <img src="uploads/profileu<?=$userid?>u.jpg?=<?php echo rand() . "\n";?>">
  <label class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="form.submit()" style="display:none">
  </label>
</form>
```

I should also note the images are uploaded to and displayed from a local folder (working correctly) and the the SQL is to simply insert a 1 or 0 into database (user has image or does not have image)

Comment: That is `$_FILES['file']`, notice the `S`.

Comment: Typo. Changed but same result

Comment: Is the jQuery function defined before or after the HTML markup? And remove the inline `onchange="form.submit()"` where `form` is undefined.

Comment: the `jQuery` is defined after. `onchange` removed but same result.

Comment: Are you sure about your SQL syntax? It looks weird to me. I think I would `var_dump($_FILES['file'])` to see if it is all good... And then focus on the SQL.

Comment: Normally, That SQL should be like  `INSERT INTO images (column1, column2, column3) VALUES(value1, value2, value3)`... So it looks like the column names are missing.

Comment: 100%. its using a function I defined on the Database page.  I've tested it without the if statement to ensure the syntax is correct and it inserted the info correctly which tells me the issue lies with the if statement meaning that I need to alter either the if statement, or change the `JQuery` so that it can auto submit with a hidden submit button.

Comment: Okay... So we'll focus on jQuery then... Try this test : `console.log(typeof($));` It should say "function".

Comment: Where should I put it? It doesn't say anything at the moment.

Comment: Within `<script>` and `</script>` at the bottom of the page, before `</html>`. And look at the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337)!

Comment: Yes it says function

Comment: ok.... And is there any error in red?

Comment: No errors at all

Comment: Is there more than 1 `id="target"` or more than 1 `id="file"` in your markup?

Comment: Just one for each

Comment: mmm... Can you paste your whole code as is in [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/) and give me the link?

Comment: Got it in the end. Appreciate the help @LouysPatriceBessette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue was that I had the form `action="upload.php"` which is where the `PHP` for uploading images was all stored. Which meant I had to move my `if(isset)` statement to the top of that page instead of the page where the form was. Now it works perfectly without a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$_FILES['fileName']` not `$_FILE`

To Check if a file has been successfully uploaded use.

`if($_FILES["fileName"]["error"] == 0){ ... }`

Along with this you can check if the uploaded file is an image you can check it as:

`if(getimagesize($_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"])){
    //Its an Image
 }
 else
 {
     //Invalid Image
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Because you're inserting `$image` and `$userid` you should check if those variables are set.

Like so:

```
if (isset($image) && isset($userid)) {
  // insertion code
}
```

Comment: Both definitely set. I tried running the code without the if statement and all data was inserted correctly.